# Pandas merge rows with different operations for each column

Tags: python, pandas

Im a light weight pandas user and I've encountered a tricky scenario. I want to merge the rows of a dataset around the 'case_id'. When merging, I want the 'Gene' column to concatenate the strings alphabetically with '->' in between if they are unique. Also there are some columns that have a 0 and others that have 1, I'd like the 1 to take place of the zeros when merging.

```
df.groupby('case_id').agg(special_merge)

def special_merge(data):
    //Handle 'Gene' Column ex. KRAS->SMAD4->TP53
    //Handle 0 vs 1
```

[image]

Comment: Not clear on the last sentence.  If 0's and 1's are in different columns, and operations are done separately for each column, how do 1's in one column take place of 0's in another column?  Or do you just want all 0's be replaced with 1's?

Comment: Also, are the strings to be concatenated already in the 'Gene' column, or will that be a new column that concatenates strings from some other column or columns?

Comment: Yes the strings are already in the 'Gene' column. Regarding the 0's and 1's - say we have column 'X' and in one row the value is 0 and in the other row its 1. When these two rows are merge, i'd like column 'X' to hold 1.

Comment: would you like show us some sample data

Comment: @Wen-Ben I added a screen shot of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared a sample data frame, based on how I understand your input data.  And then you can see aggregations done to create a new data frame.

```
orig_df = pd.DataFrame({'case_id':[1,2,3,2,1],'Gene':['KRAS','SMAD4','TP53','SMAD4','OTHER'],'col_X':[1,0,0,1,0], 'col_X2':[0,0,0,0,1})

    case_id Gene    col_X   col_X2
0   1       KRAS    1       0
1   2       SMAD4   0       0
2   3       TP53    0       0
3   2       SMAD4   1       0
4   1       BLAH    0       1

new_df = pd.DataFrame()

#lambda function identifies unique values of Gene and sorts them
new_df['Strings'] = orig_df.groupby('case_id')['Gene'].apply(lambda x: sorted(x.unique())).transform(lambda x: '->'.join(x))

#here, max function is used to take 1 during aggregation if 0's and 1's are present
cols_to_agg = [col for col in orig_df if col.startswith('col_')]
new_df[cols_to_agg] = orig_df.groupby('case_id')[cols_to_agg].agg(max)

    Strings col_X   col_X2
case_id     
1   BLAH->KRAS  1   1
2   SMAD4       1   0
3   TP53        0   0
```

Comment: Regarding the column X implementation - I'm going to have multiple columns like column X that I would want the max applied to. Sorry for not elaborating on that. Added a screenshot above.

Comment: How many columns are we talking about?  Is making a list of their names an option?

Comment: It could be hundreds of columns. Not sure I understand what you mean by making a list of names.

Comment: I just updated the code for a case when there are two columns.  You can see I added those columns to `cols_to_agg` list, which is then used in aggregation.  What do you think will be the easiest way to identify those hundreds of columns?

Comment: hmm thats a good question. I haven't thought about that. I think its safe to assume each column name will always start with 'ch'. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Okay, that helps.  I updated the `cols_to_agg` list definition above.  That list comprehension will give you a list of all columns that start with certain characters, col_ in my example.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'case_id':['1', '1', '1','2','2','2'],
'Gene':['KRAS','SMAD4','TP53','TP000','SMAD000','TP000'],
'ch_a':[0,1,0,0,0,0], 'ch_b':[0,0,0,1,1,0], 'ch_c':[0,0,0,1,1,0]})
```

```
  case_id     Gene  ch_a  ch_b  ch_c
0       1     KRAS     0     0     0
1       1    SMAD4     1     0     0
2       1     TP53     0     0     0
3       2    TP000     0     1     1
4       2  SMAD000     0     1     1
5       2    TP000     0     0     0
```

1) Sort by case_id, Gene

2) Apply lambda to join unique sorted strings over groups

3) Apply max to join binary variables (define by column mask) over groups

4) Merge two results together

```
binary_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('^ch_')]

df_case_gene = df.groupby('case_id')['Gene'].agg(lambda x: '->'.join(x.sort_values().unique())).reset_index()

df_case_binary_cols = df.groupby('case_id')[binary_cols].agg('max').reset_index()

df_final = df_case_gene.merge(df_case_binary_cols)
```

df_final:

```
  case_id               Gene  ch_a  ch_b  ch_c
0       1  KRAS->SMAD4->TP53     1     0     0
1       2     SMAD000->TP000     0     1     1
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I'm going to have multiple columns that are either 0 or 1. When I merge two rows and one row has zero for column 'x' and another has 1 for column 'x', I would want the value in the merged row to be 1.

Comment: Check it out now

Comment: What does `df.\` do?

Comment: its just a line greak. 
it is really:

Comment: df_binary_cols = df.groupby('case_id')[binary_cols].agg('max').reset_index()

Comment: added mask for coluns starting from 'ch_'